# accessing the local web service from Android device

Tags: android, web-services, local

I have a web service and it is locally in my PC. I want to test my application on a real device (not an emulator) using the locally web service.

I searched in google and I found that I have to change the IP to be myPC IP. I made that but it didn't work for me. I also remove the firewall and still no result.

Could someone help me please to fix this problem?

in the LogCat, it shows only one error which is: (thread start)
and I have INTERNET permission in the manifest.xml

this is the web.config of the web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->

```
<configSections>

  <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
      <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
        <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

-->

```
<system.web>
   <!-- 
        Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
        symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
        affects performance, set this value to true only 
        during development.
    -->
    <compilation debug="false">

      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>

    </compilation>
    <!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>
    -->


  <pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </controls>
  </pages>

  <httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
  </httpHandlers>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </httpModules>


</system.web>

<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4"
              type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
      <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
    </compiler>
    <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4"
              type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
      <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
      <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
    </compiler>
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>

<!-- 
    The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
    Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
-->
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules>
    <remove name="ScriptModule" />
    <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
    <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
    <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
    <remove name="ScriptResource" />
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode"
         type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
         type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>

<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post your logcat output and the code where you are trying to do the acccess. Also does your AppManifest has Internet Permission.

Comment: @Mobility I added what you asked me to add by editing the question.

Comment: You areusing a background process to access the web service. Can you access the service url from the device browser.

Comment: @Mobility I type the same link I posted above in the device browser but it didn't open the web service.

Comment: looks like you cannot access your machine from the device at all. How is the device and the machine connected. Are they connected to the same network?

Comment: @Mobility sorry but How could I know about that?

Comment: How are you connecting to internet from the device and machine?

Comment: @Mobility yes they both are connected to the same Wireless network. (Wifi)

Comment: Check the device ip from the wifi settings and check if you can ping the device from the machine.

Comment: @Mobility yes I can Ping it

Comment: @Mobility It shows me that all packets recieved and no one lost

Comment: Make sure your webservice on the machine is running and responding. test via browser ont the machine itself.

Comment: @Mobility it works on the machine properly.

Comment: PLease share the code you are using to access the service.

Comment: @Mobility posted above.

Comment: The function Call in WBS class is not being called directly from the main thread?

Comment: @Mobility I don't have the class WBS. But I have wbsThread which extends Thread. And it doesn't call the function Call.

Comment: Sorry I meant the WBScall class. Then how do access the call function?

Comment: Serve some trivial page and verify you can reach that by manually entering the numeric-IP URL into the Android web browser.

Comment: @Mobility really I don't understand. I will post the code of class wbsThread if you need it

Comment: @ChrisStratton if you mean like for example: www.google.com, its numaric ip is: 173.194.41.176 I entered that IP in the mobile browser and it opened the google page

Comment: @Mobility I posted the code

Comment: No, try to access a page served from your PC with the phone's browser - to get your software out of the picture and look only at the network and your web server.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am really soory to annoy but do you mean I should open any web page on the PC, then open the mobile browser and open the same page that opened on the PC but with the numaric IP?

Comment: No, I mean you should **serve** a trivial normal static html webpage (or something compatible with a generic web browser) from the webserver on your PC you are trying to use, and verify that you can load it from the stock browser on the Android device.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It didn't load. it said: Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:XXXXX

Comment: Localhost only ever refers to a machine itself, so you asked it to connect to a web server which would have to be running on the phone itself.  I had suggested you try to contact the numeric IP address of the PC, as you claimed you had in your question.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Sorry I forget!! I retried with my PC numaric ip. and still the same message. (could not connect to XXX.XXX.XXX.XX)

Comment: Then the problem is not with your android code, but rather with your network(s), your web server, or your PC's configuration.  You might try from another PC on the network, too - you *should* get the same result from that.

Comment: @ChrisStratton how to set the PC configuration?

Comment: Sorry, but while that is very much the direction you should be investigating at this point, it is getting off topic for stackoverflow.  You might want to ask about that on serverfault - and be sure to specify the web server and host operating system.

Comment: One thing you can check is that you have configured your IIS site to listen on All Ip's * rather than some fixed ip like 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Mobility Thanks. but from where can I check that?

Comment: @Mobility Could you please guide me? I posted the web.config file of the web service above.. I hope it will be helpful to configure the reason for not connecting.

Comment: @Mobility if there is no-way to solve my problem, i will upload the web service to the server. would you recommend me to upload it? and what changes should I apply in this  case? please I need your help.

Comment: You can check your site settings and that will show you what IP you have assigned to the site.

Comment: @Mobility do you mean checking my web service setting? and how to check the settings?

Comment: Go to IIS and click on the site where you are hosting your web service. On the rightmost pane you will see bindings. Check that it listens on port 80 for http protocol and IP Address is set to *

Comment: @Mobility I am really sorry :( But I created the web service using asp.NET. and the name space is: [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]. so should I go to hat site or where? what do you mean by (Go to IIS)? how to go there? I am really sorry but I have no idea.

Comment: When you run your webservice from Visual Studio is it using IIS express or IIS? You can check that under your project properties in the web section

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49631/discussion-between-user3287580-and-mobility)

Comment: @Mobility please see the chatting

Comment: @Mobility Could you please come to chatting?